# upload photos to facebook using the API

Tags: php, .net, facebook, api

I'm looking for an example code/article in PHP or .net how upload and mark upload photos to facebook using API. 
it's possible?
if can't with API, how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  $file= '/path/filename.jpg';
    $args = array(
       'message' => 'Photo from application',
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //returns the photo id
    print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```